# Как стилизовать button под высоту input'a?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Всем привет! Пример моего кода:

```css
#seachByEmail {
  background-color: #33494C; 
  border: 1px #2F4F23 outset; 
  height: 25px; 
   color: #AFCF00;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;
}
label {
  width: 94%; 
  margin: 5px auto 5px; 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBDBDB; 
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
input {
  display: inline; 
  width: 50%; 
  margin: 5px auto 20px;
  border: 3px outset rgba(137,20,167,1.00); 
  color: #0E2CC6;
  font-size: 0.99em; 
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<label for="email">Email</label>
  <span>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" id="email"/>
    <button id="seachByEmail" disabled type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 1.3em"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
```

Но оно выглядит не по феншую, т.е. кнопка находится не совсем ровно. Как её выровнять в этом случае?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/p526cjg8/

Comment: @soledar10  О, спасибо. То что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-form{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
.b-form__label{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px auto 5px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #DBDBDB;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.b-form__item{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.b-form__input{
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 3px outset rgba(137, 20, 167, 1.00);
  color: #0E2CC6;
  font-size: 0.99em;    
}
.b-form__submit{
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #33494C;
  border: 1px #2F4F23 outset;
  color: #AFCF00;    
}
.b-form__submit i{
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="b-form">
  <label for="email" class="b-form__label">Email</label>
  <div class="b-form__item">
    <input class="b-form__input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
    <button class="b-form__submit" disabled type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что это не самый лучший вариант, но попробуйте добавить `padding: 5px 6px 19px 6px;` для кнопки `#seachByEmail`.

```
#seachByEmail {
  padding: 5px 6px 19px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Да он и не такой уж и плохой. Хотя `line-height: 22px` заменяет этот `padding`